# tikz-feynman; size of lines and alignment of text

Tags: feynman, tikz-feynman

Consider the following piece of code

```
\begin{equation*}
    \feynmandiagram [medium, vertical=e to f] {
        a -- [photon] b [particle={\(\nu\)}] -- [fermion, edge label=\(k_{2}\)] c [particle={\(\rho\)}] -- [photon] d,
        b  -- [anti fermion, edge label'=\(k_{1}\)] e [particle={\(\mu\)}] -- [anti fermion, edge label'=\(k_{3}\)] c,
        e -- [photon] f,
    };
    \qquad \text{and} \qquad
    \feynmandiagram [medium, vertical=e to f] {
        a -- [photon] b [particle={\(\nu\)}] -- [anti fermion, edge label=\(-k_{2}\)] c [particle={\(\rho\)}] -- [photon] d,
        b  -- [fermion, edge label'=\(-k_{1}\)] e [particle={\(\mu\)}] -- [fermion, edge label'=\(-k_{3}\)] c,
        e -- [photon] f,
    };
    \end{equation*}
```

which generates the output

[image].

- How do I make the photon lines shorter?
- How do I make the text 'and' go in the center of the figure and not in the bottom center of the figure?
- How I do move the labels mu, nu and rho so that the lines join at vertices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To address each of these points:

- For the vertical alignment, use the `baseline` key, as in the example below.
- For shortening the photons I can't give you an automatic solution that doesn't involve shrinking the middle part as well, but you can move the end points of those lines by using `nudge` (see the manual for TikZ). I see that the amount of nudging could be fine tuned.
- Instead of `particle=\(nu\)`, use `label=\(\nu\)` which places the `\nu` beside the vertex instead of replacing the vertex with the litter.  You can further adjust the positioning of the label with `label=<angle>:\(nu\)`.

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
  \feynmandiagram [baseline={(current bounding box.center)},medium, vertical=e to f] {
    a [nudge=(-30:5mm)]
    -- [photon] b [label=60:\(\nu\)]
    -- [fermion, edge label=\(k_{2}\)] c [label=-30:\(\rho\)]
    -- [photon] d[nudge=(210:5mm)],
    b
    -- [anti fermion, edge label'=\(k_{1}\)] e [label=180:\(\mu\)]
    -- [anti fermion, edge label'=\(k_{3}\)] c,
    e -- [photon] f[nudge up=10mm],
  };
  \qquad \text{and} \qquad
  \feynmandiagram [baseline={(current bounding box.center)},medium, vertical=e to f] {
    a [nudge=(-30:5mm)]
    -- [photon] b [label=60:\(\nu\)]
    -- [anti fermion, edge label=\(-k_{2}\)] c [label=-30:\(\rho\)]
    -- [photon] d[nudge=(210:5mm)],
    b
    -- [fermion, edge label'=\(-k_{1}\)] e [label=180:\(\mu\)]
    -- [fermion, edge label'=\(-k_{3}\)] c,
    e -- [photon] f[nudge up=10mm],
  };
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```